# Decrease quantity on place order not working magento 2

Tags: magento2.4

Which file is responsible for qty update/stock decrease when an order is placed?

I am trying to fix an issue where "qty not getting decreased when order is placed".

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: GO to the Store->Configuration->catalog->inventory->stock Option tab and check that 'Decrease Stock When Order is Placed' is set to 'yes'

Comment: I have checked this & its not working.

Comment: Did you customize anything on place order?any extensions or custom work at place order?

Comment: No @Mehran. 
I have not.

Comment: Can you advise me on which file is responsible for qty update/stock decrease when an order is placed?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: check this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Product-quantity-does-not-change-or-decreased-when-ordering/td-p/128420